# Maybe getting a character from a list of strings

Tags: strings, null, purescript

I'm trying to transition from JavaScript to PureScript (a Haskell spinoff that transpiles to JavaScript). For starters I coded this:

```
getAt :: [String] -> Number -> Number -> String
getAt strings x y = case strings !! y of
    Nothing -> " "
    Just line -> case charAt x line of
        Nothing -> " "
        Just char -> fromChar char

-- getAt ["abc", "def"] 0 1 -- returns "d"
```

It retrieves a character at position (x, y) from a "grid" of characters given as an arrays of strings. I can't help but think that the same function would be just `return strings[y][x]` in JavaScript assuming that (x, y) are always within bounds - which is true in my case. I can't get rid of these functions that return `Maybe`, but can I at least write this in a more concise way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't used PureScript, but in Haskell the most straightforward way to do this would be to leverage the `Monad` instance for `Maybe` and write your function using `do`-notation. From toying around with http://try.purescript.org/ I think this should work.

```
getAt :: [String] -> Number -> Number -> String
getAt strings x y = fromMaybe " " $ do line <- strings !! y
                                       char <- charAt x line
                                       return $ fromChar char
```

Note the use of `fromMaybe`, after you've done your computation in the `Maybe` monad, you get back out by specifying a "default" to use in the case that any value of `Nothing` cropped up, causing the whole `do`-block to return `Nothing`.